# ¿como puedo unir arreglo y repetirlo?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola soy nuevo en esto, me podrían ayudar o guiar. tengo este archivo y lo pase a javascript para poder hacer lo que necesito, gracias por ayuda.

tengo esto solamente. que es un arreglo

```
const datos = [{
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: '',
  },
  {
     titulo: 'Portabilidad con equipo',
     descripcion: 'Obtén más descuentos contratando desde 2 o más líneas',
     url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/telefonia-movil/portabilidad-con-equipo/',
     keywords: '',
  },]
```

y este otro arreglo que serian las keywords

```
const keywords = [
     key = [

        'fibra empresas',
         'internet fibra',
         'fibra óptica',
         'fibra simétrica',
         'Giga simétrica',
         ' internet empresas'
     ],
     key = [
        'portabilidad con equipo',
        'portabilidad empresas'
     ],
 ]
```

necesito imprimir esto con cada keywords y esto lo que quiero de salida, en un console.log, nose si quedo claro. y si fueran mas de uno, asi como lo edite, es que hay mas objetos

```
[
{
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: 'fibra empresa',
  },
  {
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: 'internet fibra',
  },
  {
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: 'fibra optica',
  },
  {
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: 'fibra simetrica',
  },
  {
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: 'Giga simetrica',
  },
  {
    titulo: 'Internet Fibra Empresas',
    descripcion: 'Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.',
    url: 'https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/',
    keywords: 'internet empresas',
  },
]
```

Comment: Checa [esto](https://playcode.io/882893) y ve a ver si es lo que quieres. Tienes errores de sintaxis en los objetos que pusiste.

Comment: si gracias, consulta que significa los ... puntos ...datos

Comment: Se llama spread operator. Puedes buscar info en mdn. Basicamente lo que hace es: lo que tiene ya ...miObjeto, agregale lo que viene en miObjeto.miPropiedad

Comment: que pasaría si fueran varios, lo edite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien creo que esto te debería funcionar.

```
const datos = [
    {
        titulo: "Internet Fibra Empresas",
        descripcion: "Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.",
        url: "https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/",
        keywords: "",
    },
];

const keywords = [
    (key = [
        "fibra empresas",
        "internet fibra",
        "fibra óptica",
        "fibra simétrica",
        "Giga simétrica",
        " internet empresas",
    ]),
];

nuevosDatos = [];

// Por cada key en keywords, busca en datos las propiedades y agrega a nuevosDatos
keywords[0].forEach((key) => {
    nuevosDatos.push({
        titulo: datos[0].titulo,
        descripcion: datos[0].descripcion,
        url: datos[0].url,
        keywords: key,
    });
});

console.log(nuevosDatos);
```

Se podrían simplificar mas cosas como en keywords y usar directamente los datos:

```
const datos = [];

const keywords = [
    "fibra empresas",
    "internet fibra",
    "fibra óptica",
    "fibra simétrica",
    "Giga simétrica",
    " internet empresas",
];

keywords.forEach((key) => {
    datos.push({
        titulo: "Internet Fibra Empresas",
        descripcion: "Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.",
        url: "https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/",
        keywords: key,
    });
});

console.log(datos);
```

SI FUERAN MAS DATOS:

```
const datos = [
    {
        titulo: "Internet Fibra Empresas",
        descripcion: "Únete a la fibra óptica de Movistar Empresas.",
        url: "https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/internet-fijo/internet-empresas/",
        keywords: "",
    },
    {
        titulo: "Portabilidad con equipo",
        descripcion: "Obtén más descuentos contratando desde 2 o más líneas",
        url: "https://ww2.movistar.cl/empresas/productos-y-servicios/telefonia-movil/portabilidad-con-equipo/",
        keywords: "",
    },
];

const keywords = [
    (key = [
        "fibra empresas",
        "internet fibra",
        "fibra óptica",
        "fibra simétrica",
        "Giga simétrica",
        " internet empresas",
    ]),
    (key = ["portabilidad con equipo", "portabilidad empresas"]),
];

let nuevosDatos = [];

for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    keywords[i].forEach((key) => {
        nuevosDatos.push({
            titulo: datos[i].titulo,
            descripcion: datos[i].descripcion,
            url: datos[i].url,
            keywords: key,
        });
    });
}

console.log(nuevosDatos);
```

Comment: que pasaria si fueran varios

Comment: @maximiliano ahí edite mi respuesta